# Writing an adaptor for JBoss Fuse

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, modbus-tcp

I'd like to use JBoss Fuse to translate web service calls to Modbus/TCP messages (and vice versa). There doesn't seem to exist a third-party adaptor for this protocol, so I suppose I have to write it myself. How is this done?

Currently, my best guess is that JBoss Fuse stores the SOAP file of the web service call as a file and passes it to Apache Camel. So all I have to do is to write a converter for these file formats. Is this correct?

Comment: Don't try to understand my question... I've phrased it in a convoluted way because I was very confused when I wrote it. However, the answer given by  @Namphibian is great. They've answered the question I've tried (but failed) to ask.

Comment: how you achieved your tasks? i am also looking for same component

Comment: I didn't. JBoss Fuse is a great tool if you've got the right usecase. I've managed to convince our customer that our usecase is different. After that, we were allowed to provide good old SOAP webservices, and everything became a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption is not correct. Depending on which component you used for the web services call the underlying technology would be different. For example using CXF component to call a web service means that CXF does the service interaction. Also I have never seen a SOAP file. SOAP is a protocol not a file type. Maybe you are thinking of a wsdl?

Two ways to achieve what you want:

1. Create a component which will act as a Modbus producer and consumer. This is a long road and the ModBus/TCP component will only read/write Modbus protocol you would still need to translate the SOAP/Rest or other protocols into the ModBus one.
2. Use a TCP component such as Netty, MINA or MINA2 to write ModBus. Check out this [Modbus TCP client/server implementation in Java with Netty 4.x](https://github.com/klymenek/modjn) project at GitHub.

Remember the components only talk and read from the system they were created for i.e. SalesForce wont understand SAP, Rest components don't speak SOAP, Files components don't understand TCP. You would need to map/translate still.